# Rails & MySQL: Array winds up with ---[] or --- stored in the DB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am extracting a series of strings from an XML stream and storing them in a mySQL Database (tried with VARCHAR and TEXT). At the start of each array, in the DB, I get `---` and then either a `[]` if it is a blank array or the values.

Rake task code:

```
@issue = Array.new  
items.each do |item| #items is the parsed elements from XML
    link_key = item.xpath('key').inner_text
    @issue << link_key
    Rails.logger.debug("Issue: #{@issue.inspect}")
  end
```

Database value example:

"--- []"

-or-

"--- 
 - CR-3528"

Not sure what else would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're serializing an array.

One way to deal with this is to mark a field as serialized with `serialize` ([docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class)):

```
serialize :issue
```

See [this](http://www.edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2011/03/09/custom-activerecord-attribute-serialization/index.html) for additional details.

If you had been storing the value as text, you should not have seen this--it would have been just the text.

Comment: Well bust my buffers and steal my chocolate. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottJShea Heh ;) Those guys thought of everything. Sometimes.